# Oracle Lite - Cannot connect to newly created DB. [POL-3013]

Tags: database, oracle, embedded-database

I get an error when I try to connect to my newly created Oracle Lite database.
But I can connect to the orabpel DB that was created with the Oracle SOA install.

Here are the steps I took to create it:

1. Ran: `createdb polite db1 manager`
2. Result:

   ```
   Oracle Lite CREATEDB Version 10.2.0.2.0.
   Copyright (c) 1997, 2005, Oracle. All rights reserved.
   Database C:\SOFTWARE\ORACLEAS\MOBILE\SDK\OLDB40\DB1.odb created (VolID = 1738).
   ```
3. Ran: `validatedb polite db1`
4. Result: No errors found!
5. Ran: `msql system/manager@jdbc:polite:db1`

6: Result: `[POL-3013] bad database or invalid password.`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the result of the following command? 

validatedb polite db1 -l system:manager

This would likely confirm whether the database is bad or if there is a username/password issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A95916_01/emgtext.htm#i1004863) the error means:

> POL-3013 Bad database or invalid password
>
> Cause: The database failed to open a database or log file, or the file header was corrupted. Possibly caused by using an incorrect password to decrypt the database.
>
> Action: Give the correct password, check your hard drive, or reboot the operating system.

I don't know if it helps, but I found a similar question with an answer on an [Oracle forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=1351586).

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this particular DB, but I've seen issues before where a new DB allowed local but not remote access to the default account.  I had to either create a new user with remote access privileges or add those privileges to the default user (obviously the details depend on your DB).

Vague, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Well, I am only connecting locally so that shouldn't be a problem. (Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Change the database name configured in ODBC.

Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC).  Find the "POLite" entry under the "User DSN" tab and edit it. Change the "Database" field to "db1" so it matches the name of the database you created.